# An episode from Spider-Man animated series (1994-1998) in which he has a dream sequence or an hallucination about being an actual spider

Tags: marvel, episode-identification, spider-man

I'm practically sure this was part of an episode from the [*Spider-Man: The Animated Series* (1994-1998)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112175/), although I can't remember anything else from that episode.

The way I remember it, there was a tiny spider in the sink with a human head (with the face of Peter Parker). Aunt May was "fighting" it, while Peter tried to tell her something in the line of "It's me!", which she couldn't hear because he was a tiny spider. After a short sequence, she turned on the tap, and the stream of water pulled the Peter headed spider into the drain.

The next sequence depicted a giant spider walking in the city. Although it looked giant, it still had a regular sized human head (with the face of Peter Parker). People ran away, as Peter begged them for help.

What makes me think this was either a dream of some kind or an hallucination is the fact that these sequences were very short and happened very fast, although I can't remember anything about what happened before or after, so I can't tell for certain.

I tried searching up for Spider-Man animated series nightmare and dream sequences, and all I was able to find were an episode titled "Nightmare" (which doesn't seem to have that scene, as far as I could see), and a dream where a giant Venom is fighting against a giant Spider-Man costume to take over Peter Parker.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The episode that you're referring to is from *Season 3 Episode 2 (Sins of the Fathers Chapter 2: Make a Wish)*.

In this episode, Spider-Man meets a young girl named Tina who is his biggest fan. While telling her about how he became Spider-Man, Peter tells her about a dream/nightmare that he had. That is the one you're referring to in your question.

Watch this video of the dream sequence:

Comment: There are times like this when I'm impressed by how fast the answer came.

Comment: @Clockwork you're in luck because I am rewatching the old stuff since the past few weeks and coincidentally, I watched this exact episode a few days ago.

Comment: For anyone reading, the Youtube video is no longer available, but the Dailymotion link that was available in the first revision of the answer is still working